# How to make sure imported module works when importing functions from another Python script?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

To simplify my current script, I decided to move some functions to a separate script. One of them is this below one:

```
def get_soup(url):
    """
    Given the url of a page, this function returns the soup object.

    Parameters:
        url: the link to get soup object for

    Returns:
        soup: soup object
    """

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    driver.close()

    return soup
```

This function is put in a file that's called `scrape_data.py`. However, when I use this function after importing it in my current script, I got `NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined`. This happens even after I import BeautifulSoup in my current script like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
```

So how can I make this work? Should I import the function's needed module/library in the function itself (which doesn't work for me either)? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to import an object into the module (Python file) you want to use it.

Comment: What @KlausD. means is that you have to include the line `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` also in the file where you isolated the function.

Comment: @JosepValls I tried that, but still getting the same error...

Comment: Add the line to the file, then __restart the kernel__ and run the code again.

Comment: Thank you @EdgarR.Mondragón! Restarting the kernel seems to fix the issue for me after adding the import line mentioned above to the import from file.